# Mysql: How to get every rows that have more than a certain number of decimal after the dot

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table that contains float values.

### table

```
+   id   |  value  |
+--------|---------|
+   1    | 19.22   |
+   2    | 32.333  |
+   3    | 1.2332  |
+   4    | 0.22334 |
+   5    | 4.55    |
```

I want to extract every row that contains more than 3 decimal after the dot.

## The result I would expect is:

```
+   id   |  value  |
+--------|---------|
+   2    | 32.333  |
+   3    | 1.2332  |
+   4    | 0.22334 |
```

Comment: Technically, they all have values beyond the third decimal -- they're just zeros.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Cast the `value` column as a `varchar` and use string comparison.

Comment: Thanks, here is the query I used: "SELECT value FROM table t WHERE cast(value as CHAR) LIKE '%.___%'"

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me:

```
SELECT  *
FROM table
WHERE column <> ROUND (column,2)
```

or:

```
SELECT  *
FROM table
WHERE column <> CAST (column AS DECIMAL(36,2))
```

Answer (score 4):

This [regex (MySQL 5.0+)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/cast-functions.html) worked for me, based on the data you provided:

```
SELECT t.* 
  FROM YOUR_TABLE t 
 WHERE t.`value` REGEXP '[0-9]+.[0-9][0-9][0-9]+'
```

Reference:

- http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table` 
WHERE LENGTH(SUBSTR(`value`,INSTR(`value`,"."))) >3
```

Counting the decimal .01 is 3, .011 is 4

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select value, LEN(value) - CHARINDEX('.', value) as DecimalCount from Table
where LEN(value) - CHARINDEX('.', value) > 2
```

NOTE:   I'm not using mySQL, I have MSSQL.  let me know if this works for you - just noticed you asked for a mySQL solution.

**UPDATE:**  Felt bad for answering for the wrong platform.  A bit of research got me this for mySQL:

```
select * from Table
where LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, '.', -1)) > 2
```

Answer (score 1):

SELECT * 
  FROM table t 
 WHERE floor(t.columnname)!=t.columnname

Comment: How this solves the "more than 3 decimals" criteria?

Comment: Thanks @Surendra Sharma, your answer is the best for me, with: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE floor(table.columnname) = table.columnname` I can select rows WITHOUT decimal/float, greath! :-)

Answer (score 0):

**SQL Server:**
To extract values with more than 3 decimal places from the "quantity" column in a SQL table with the "quantity" column using float data type, you can use the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
WHERE ROUND(quantity, 3) <> quantity;
```